# converting a string to a number

Tags: vbscript

I have a script that receives a string that contains a number.

The string may be "1000" or "1000.25" or "1111111111111111111111111" or "abc111"

I would like to be able to check firstly if it is a number, and fail if it is not, and also fail if there are fractions.

I am having trouble converting to a suitable number type that still lets me check for the mentioned scenarios.

Basically I need to check that the string only contains an integer number, no matter how large that number may be.

Would really appreciate some help on this one.

Thanks

Dave

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the function I've used to achieve what you want:

```
Function is_numeric(ByVal sText)
    Dim iCnt, sChr

    is_numeric = True

    If IsNull(sText) OR sText = "" Then
        is_numeric = False
        Exit Function
    End If

    If sText = "" Then
        is_numeric = False
        Exit Function
    End If

    For iCnt = 1 To Len(sText)
        sChr = Mid(sText, iCnt, 1)
            If Asc(sChr) < 48 OR Asc(sChr) > 57 Then
            is_numeric = False
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I like this solution but have modified slightly to do an isNumeric on each character in the string, which should fail for all non numeric characters.

Answer (score 2):

Use **IsNumeric** to check if is a number and then use **CInt** to convert

Comment: Keep in mind that the integer data type is limited to the range -32,768 to 32,767.  You may want to use the long data type (convert with clng()) instead, which is limited to the range -2,147,483,648 to 2,147,483,647.  I just tested and got an overflow error when running cint(32768) or clng(2147483648).

Answer (score 0):

Did you have a chance to discover [CInt](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fctcwhw9%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and CDbl already?